# What's the different between native-mt and normal kotlin coroutine lib?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

When we use coroutine, we can either have the normal kotlin coroutine or the `native-mt` version.

i.e.

```
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0'
```

or

```
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0-native-mt'
```

Is there any difference between them? When should we use which?

Answer (score 15):

It basically provides capability to use multiple threads in Kotlin/Native code  (typically as part of a Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP) project).  Some more info at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/concurrency-and-coroutines.html#multithreaded-coroutines.  This is also version used now by many KMP libraries (e.g. `Ktor`) and is generally a requirement when developing KMP apps.

Comment: Just fyi that you shouldn't need to use the native-mt dependency any more.....with use now of new memory model that was enabled by default in Kotlin 1.7.20 https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-memory-manager.html