# org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android vs org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:*-native-mt

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

New to Android development and I’m confused between these two libraries and why I would want one over the other for Android.  I’ve reviewed the following:

•    https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-concurrency-and-coroutines.html#multithreaded-coroutines

•   https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/12/introducing-kotlinx-coroutines-1-6-0/

•   [What's the different between native-mt and normal kotlin coroutine lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67856900/whats-the-different-between-native-mt-and-normal-kotlin-coroutine-lib)

•   [Multithreaded version of coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69857553/multithreaded-version-of-coroutines)

It’s still not clear to me how this applies to an Android-only project.  As I understand it, native-mt applies to Native, so why is this available for Android?

Thank you.

Comment: same here, i dont get which one of these two i should use: org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services
or
org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android